# for java package org.rosuda.REngine.REXP

Tags: java

Hi All: I want to use org.rosuda.REngine.REXP &  org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection class in my code. For that, i need org.apache.java package. Is it a free source package and Where shall i downloa

Comment: apache has a HUGE collection of Java libraries, all in the package org.apache. Which library do you need exactly? What's the full name of the packages? Anyway, Look at http://projects.apache.org/indexes/quick.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

- [Apache harmony](http://harmony.apache.org/) - an open source implementation of java

I look at the rosuda.org pages but the documentation for REngine didn't help identifying any required apache libraries. We'd need more input if you need something different.